# How to let absolute path work on both local and remote servers?

Tags: php, html, localhost, relative-path, absolute-path

I am creating a website that has to be edited on the **local server** and then uploaded later on the **remote server**. I'm using absolute path on the local server but then when I upload it to the remote server, links don't work anymore. It seems that I can only use either relative or absolute, not both.

I want the script to work on both local as well as remote server. Local is obviously for editing (sometimes I used to have slow internet connection so I have to use localhost). And Remote for production purposes and client preview.

Below is the function I created:

PHP SCRIPT:

```
define("LOCALHOST", "/adamsProject");
define("REMOTE_SERVER", "http://adamsproject.ph");

function host(){
    if(!LOCALHOST){
        echo REMOTE_SERVER;
    }else{
        echo LOCALHOST;
    }
}
```

EXECUTION ON HTML:

```
<ul>

    <a href="index.php"><img src=" <?php echo host(); ?> /images/logoMain.png" id="logoMain" > </a>

    <li><a href=" <?php echo host(); ?> /index.php"> HOME </a></li><li>
    <a href="#" id="servicesWide"> SERVICES <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li><li>
    <a href=" <?php echo host(); ?> /underConstruction.php"> ABOUT US </a></li><li>
    <a href=" <?php echo host(); ?> /pages/contactUs.php"> CONTACT US </a></li><li>
    <a href="#" id="folioWide"> PORTFOLIO <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: If your function echoes data, you don't want to echo the function, it's like `echo echo 'text'`. If you echo the function, the function should `return` data, not `echo` it.

Comment: @DeDee. Thank man! Now I know. What do you think. Is my function correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like DeDee said, You probably want to remove the echos in the link and also the spaces right after the 'host(); ?>' See the code below. Also, no need for the PHP function; you can use "$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']" that grabs the current web server name. I hope this helps.

```
if(!$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']='localhost'){
$domain = '/adamsProject';
} else {
   $domain = 'http://www.adamsproject.ph';   
}
?>
<ul>
<a href="<?php echo $domain;?>/index.php"><img src="<?php echo $domain;?>/images/logoMain.png" id="logoMain" > </a>
<li><a href="<?php echo $domain;?>/index.php"> HOME </a></li><li>
<a href="#" id="servicesWide"> SERVICES <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li><li>
<a href="<?php echo $domain;?>/underConstruction.php"> ABOUT US </a></li><li>
<a href="<?php echo $domain;?>/pages/contactUs.php"> CONTACT US </a></li><li>
<a href="#" id="folioWide"> PORTFOLIO <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**
Per your comments, if you have a sub directory off of you 'localhost' then you may need a if statement to add your 'adamsProject' directory to your domain when you are on local host. Try that. Let me know.

**EDIT2**
Replaced remote server domain with your hard coded domain. Also, added `$domain` to your index.php on home img link and HOME nav link.

Comment: `<a href="index.php"><img src="<?php $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/images/logoMain.png" id="logoMain" > </a>` Interestingly enough, this one is not working for me. Maybe, some kind of ghost in a machine. I'm using XAMPP. My PHP version is: 5.6.8 and my Apache is: 2.4.12.

Comment: Hmm. That is odd. It works for me. For example, the 'ABOUT US' link produces 'http://localhost/underConstruction.php' when the page is rendered. Did you try just have a test page with only: `<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>`
To see if it echos 'localhost'?

Comment: My php version 5.5.18 is Apache is 2.4.10; But should work on your configuration.

Comment: I've created another answer for you to try out @JOE

Comment: Yes, Chad. It affirmatively echoed "localhost".

Comment: Yes, Chad. It affirmatively echoed "localhost". Note: the ABOUT US page is not in the root directory, it's in the subfolder. **index.php** is the only page that is in the root directory. So, it goes like this: **localhost/adamsProject/includes/navMain.php**. Where **navMain.php** is the navigation bar where ABOUT US link is located. And where **adamsProject** is the **root folder**.

Comment: It worked fine at the localhost. Then I tried uploading it to the remote server, it did not worked. By the way. This one worked just fine: `/adamsProject/images/logoMain.png`. In fact, I don't need to use PHP script on this. But as the same, it refuse to work at the remote server. `/adamsProject` is my root or main folder.

Comment: There is something I am missing from your problem. Can you please provide the link it renders on your remote server (you can mask the domain (www.****.com)) I just want to see what it is creating. Also, provide the link it creates on your localhost you said it works so i assume it is: localhost/adamsProject/pages/contactUs.php

Comment: Yeah, you're right. That's `localhost/adamsProject/pages/contactUs.php`. In the local. In the remote: `www.adamsproject.ph/pages/contactUs.php`.

Comment: Isn't the remote link you provided what you want (www.adamsproject.ph/pages/contactUs.php)?

Comment: The problem is the remote link or remote server. Absolute path works fine at the local. But not at the remote. If you can see the links at www.adamsproject.ph/pages/contactUs.php are all messed up. But at my local everything is fine just by using /adamsProject alone to every link. Amazing dilemma, isn't it? :-)

Comment: if you see the link it creates for me it looks like what you want, is it not? http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zy6E.png

Comment: Yup, that's exactly is the link. But even at the `navMain.php` level absolute path don't work at the remote server.

Comment: Its hard to understand without screenshot or code examples. Can you provide? Lets get this resolved. lol. So even a hard coded Abs path doesnt work? that sounds like another issue if thats the case, if not, lets see the example.

Comment: Thank for staying with me :-) This is the screen shot of my navMain.php which is inside my includes folder. http://i.imgur.com/QV3gXwj.jpg and here is my folder structure: http://i.imgur.com/re8hCcx.jpg

Comment: At first glance i see spaces in your code in your img src `<img src="<?php echo $domain;?>/images/logoMain.png" id="logoMain" >` should be no spaces within the quotes outside of the php tags

Comment: Also, your index.php links should also be the full path too bc say they are within your '/pages' directory, if they click on the link to go to homepage or even the 'HOME' link youll get 404 bc it cant find index within /pages

Comment: Thank man, I guess it worked! Thank you for the help man. You are the best!

Comment: NP, was your problem now the index.php path in you nav?

Comment: Neither. It's a bit from the code I created. I just modified a little bit the script you have suggested to me. And viola! http://i.imgur.com/v20VhqO.jpg

Comment: Nice, glad you got it working. However, echoing from a function is usually bad practice; you may want to look into have the function return it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try using $ _ SERVER [ ' SERVER_NAME ' ] instead of your function. It will work both for local server and remote one. Your code should look like this.

```
<ul>

<a href="index.php"><img src="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/images/logoMain.png" id="logoMain" > </a>

<li><a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/index.php"> HOME </a></li><li>
<a href="#" id="servicesWide"> SERVICES <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li><li>
<a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/underConstruction.php"> ABOUT US </a></li><li>
<a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/pages/contactUs.php"> CONTACT US </a></li><li>
<a href="#" id="folioWide"> PORTFOLIO <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </a></li></ul>
```

It will return `http://localhost/something` or `http://yourwebsite.pl/something`

You have to add `http://` before using `<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>`. If you won't it will treat is as relative path anyway and will double your server name. In this case it's treated as absolute paths. Here is an example to understand it easier:

```
Relative path:
<a href="index.php"><img src="/images/logoMain.png" id="logoMain" > </a>
Still relative path(server name doubled)
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/index.php"> HOME </a>
Absolute path (correct one):
<a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/underConstruction.php"> ABOUT US </a>
```

*Remember that `<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>`return server name without `/` in the end.

Comment: Thanks Shishibi! Interestingly, this one don't work for me. While it works with others.

Comment: Try to echo it. I saw in other answers thar you arę missing it.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope it will solve your problem now!

Comment: Thank for the kind effort man. I'v tried that and my address bar says: `http://localhost%20/underConstruction.php` and the page says `This webpage is not available.` Note: my Navigation bar in is the subfolder not in the root directory.

Comment: This one really worked well in the localhost, no problem. BUT it doesn't work anymore in the remote server. `<a href="index.php"><img src="/adamsProject/images/logoMain.png" id="logoMain" > </a>`. Just putting `/adamsProject` before `/images/logoMain.png` solves the rub --- in the localhost only.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternatively** just use relative URLs... so,

`<a href="/underConstruction.php"> ABOUT US </a>`

Will work the same on both remote and local. Rendering the page produces:

http://localhost/underConstruction.php

for me on local.